# Uniform convergence and integrability

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

If $(f_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ converges to $f$ uniformly and each $f_n$ integrable would it imply $f$ is integrable and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_n = \int f$$

In case

1. each $f_n$ is nonnegative
2. general integrable functions $f_n$

I am considering Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @Surb How we can use Dominated convergence theorem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence of functions given by
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1n&\text{if}\ 0<x<n^2\\
0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then for any $x>0$, $|f_n(x)|\leq\frac1n$ so $f_n\to f:=0$ uniformly. However,
$$\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\ dx=n\to\infty$$
whereas
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx=0.$$
This counterexample still has $f$ integrable but you get the idea.

In the case where all the $f_n$ are continuous and we are looking at a compact interval $[a,b]$ then your statement holds by a simple application of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Excellent but I didn't get the last statement. Infact this is wrong as much as I can see. If I take fn = n on [0,1/n] then this is not true.

Comment: That sequence does not converge uniformly. It is also not continuous, but that doesn't really matter - as long as each $f_n$ is bounded then the statement holds.